# How can I convert a color attribute to a mask for sculpting?

Tags: geometry-nodes, sculpting, custom-attributes

[image]
Left: Generated Mask after Mask by Color Tool ; Right: Original Color Attribute

Is there a way to convert a color attribute to a sculpting mask? I tried using the Mask by Color tool, but it loses detail even after adjusting the threshold setting. The image above demonstrates this and shows the closest I could get to the attribute. Are there any add-ons, settings, or thing I can do in Geometry Nodes that I missed that can achieve converting an attribute to a mask without altering the contrast?